# PDO returning execute results to an array

Tags: php, pdo

So I am bashing my head against the wall over a question which more than likely has a simple solution. Here is my code.

```
public function login($username, $password){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user AND password = :pass";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $data = array('user' => $username, 'pass' => md5($password . $this->salt));
        $stmt->execute($data);

        $status = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        if($status){
            echo "You are Logged in!";
            print_r($result);
        } else {
            echo $status;
            $this->error['alert'] = "You have not entered the correct login information.";
            Users::ErrorReport();
        }

    }
```

What I want to do is pull all of the data from that users row and store it in an array so that I can access it in order to store it to the class variables. I would like to do something similar to

```
while($row = $stmt->fetchAll()){
   $this->username = $row['username'];
}
```

The problem when I do this is Ive run into a million nasty errors and cant find any solutions while searching the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fetch()` instead of `fetchAll()`

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $this->username = $row['username'];
}
```

or if you like, you can use `fetchAll()` this way

```
$result_array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Update: Venu is right, it's a bit wasteful to use mixed (Numeric and Associative) if you're only gonna use associative. So it's a good idea to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: +1 for u, its always good to define fetch style.. while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))